# ATK Upload Addon

Tags: atk4

I am attempting to add an uploading interface to my site that supports multiple-file selection and drag-and-drop uploading. The Filestore add-on has worked very well for me in the past, but I need more features than it supports.

I found an upload add-on developed by Romans here: https://github.com/romaninsh/upload

The README states that the add-on uses the BlueImp Upload jQuery widget and it lists several features such as a FileList view and a DropZone controller. However, when I looked in the source code for the add-on, I didn't find classes for most of the views described in the README or for the controller. I tried following the instructions under "Stand-alone use" by adding a View_Uploader element to a page, but this only added an empty div to the page.

Is the add-on incomplete? Or is it meant to be extended before it can be functional? If this add-on isn't the best tool for the job, is there a better way to implement the kind of enhanced uploader that I need on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of that new upload add-on. It is in fact incomplete, I've planned it out and drafted features / readme but haven't had time to finish it.

The goal here is to create a View which would interact with Filestore / importFile, but uses more modern way to upload the file.

If you think you would want to take over that add-on and build it, i'll offer you some help.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. My company needs this project completed ASAP and is willing to skip the extra features in order to have the work completed sooner. Therefore, I won't be able to take over development of this addon in my main time. I may be able to contribute to it in my own time however, and will message you if I do start adding to it.

Comment: Certainly share what you've accomplished, it will help others and can be a great help in the future.